# Avoid showing two permission alerts when accessing camera using UIImagePickerController in iOS 9.3.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Thanks for reading.

I am facing a new problem in iOS 9.3.3 version, when accessing camera for first time using UIImagePickerController.

By Default, Apple shows the permission alert for the first time accessing camera in an iOS application, its works fine.

After taking a photo and tapping on Use button, Apple showing one more alert view with message - "App would like to access photos".

Tapping on OK button, I am not getting selected photo. This is happening only for the first time.But this is not happening in other versions.

I know this is not possible to avoid the alert view by iOS. But Is there any possible to suppress the second alert view after taking the photo.

Could someone please help me out?

Please see the following code:

```
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

            UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
            imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
            imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [weakSelf.parent presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                        alertControllerWithTitle:@"Camera is not available."
                                        message:nil
                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                        actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                        {

                                        }];


            [alert addAction:okAction];
            [self.parent presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        }

[self.parent presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: can you add the code of picker?

Comment: iOS shows an alert view when you try to access the camera or the photos library for the first time. Are you setting the sourceType of your picker to library anywhere else?

Comment: both alert is different one is for camera access and another is for photos. You can avoid this by asking user both permission at same time

Comment: @Mahesh Try my answer. This is for accessing gallary without permission

Comment: what is `[self.parent presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];` ? what is importMenu that you are try to presenting over presented view controller (i.e. imagepicker) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need (iOS 9 and above):

```
PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];

switch (status) 
{
    case PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
       //Write your customisation code
        break;
    case PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
    {
        [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus)
        {
            if (authorizationStatus == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
            {
                //Write your own code...
            }
            else
            {
                //Show alert view
            }
        }];
        break;
    }
    default:
        //Show alert view
        break;
}
```